# How to implement Spring Integration Flow to act as a TcpClient

Tags: spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration

I am trying to set up a Spring Integration Flow to act as a Tcp Client.
The Server is running on e.g. localhost:9026.

I first tried with simple Sockets, that worked.

I expected it to be much more simpler, but I can not make it work.
What I want to reach is, that the application establishes a connection to the server at startup and consumes each incoming message. The messages can be heart-beats or xml data.

Can anyone help? I'm really desperate.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
@EnableIntegrationManagement(defaultLoggingEnabled = "true")
public class TcplistenerApplication {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TcplistenerApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(TcplistenerApplication .class, args);

@Bean
    public AbstractConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("localhost", 9026);
        factory.setDeserializer(TcpCodecs.raw());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler inbound() {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler adapter = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        adapter.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory());
        adapter.setClientMode(true);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow tcpClientFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(clientConnectionFactory()))
                .handle(m -> LOGGER.info(m.getPayload().toString())).get();
    }

@EventListener
    public void listen(TcpConnectionEvent event) {
        LOGGER.info(event.toString());
    }

}
```

UPDATE:
I changed config in the following way, so I am able to recieve data now:
(As a first step, just logging was enough)

```
//...
@Bean
    public AbstractConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("localhost", 9026);
        factory.setDeserializer(new CustomMessageDeserializer());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow tcpClientFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(clientConnectionFactory()).clientMode(true)).log()
                .handle(m -> Logger.info(m.getPayload())).get();
    }


//...
```

CustomMessageDeserializer:

```
public class CustomMessageDeserializer implements Deserializer<CustomMessage> {

    private CustomMessageParser parser;

    public CustomMessageDeserializer() {
        this.parser = new CustomMessageParser();
    }

    @Override
    public CustomMessagedeserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer);

        return parser.parse(Arrays.copyOf(buffer, readBytes));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TcpCodecs.raw()` will only decode the stream into a message when the socket is closed; to send multiple messages over a single TCP stream, you need some structure in the data and a deserializer that understands the protocol.

See the documentation about the supplied deserializers and how to write a custom one.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-codecs

Also, if you are not sending data, you don't need the sending message handler, just set clientMode on the inbound adapter.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, that helped me a lot. I will add the corrected version to my question.